# How to improve a question about adapting algorithm?

Tags: discussion

My question about [adapting a binary tree algorithm to make it a multi-class algorithm](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/67642/how-to-adapt-my-decision-tree-for-binary-classification-to-a-decision-tree-for-m) has been closed without a comment. I have edited it, I would like to improve it to have it reopen but I can't reach the moderator who closed it for help.

What can I do to clarify my question?

Answer (score 4):

I closed the question because it is/was mainly code with little to no explanation. Besides the title there is no question about the code itself. For example there is an error shown in your code. Do you just need help fixing the error? Your question in the title suggests otherwise. A little more context would be appropriate. Viewers are left to guess what it is you need. Also other community members can also reopen the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hope I documented my code and provided enough context now. Let me know otherwise. I don't need just fixing the error, I want to adapt the binary tree algorithm to make it able to do multi-label classification